# Select rows with no match between two tables by sem

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2. I want to select distinct rows in Table2 that are not contained in Table1. Here is an example:

```
  Table1        

   | A  |   | sem|
   ------------------
1. | aa |   | 1 |
   ---------------
2. | bb |   | 1 |
   ----------------
3. | aa |   | 2 |
   -----------------
4. | cc |   | 2 |
   ---------------

Table2

   | B  |
   ------
1. | aa |
   ------
2. | aa |
   ------
3. | bb |
   ------
4. | cc |
   ------
5. | cc |
   ------
6. | ee |
   ------
7. | ee |
   ------
```

I would want the those row who is not common  in  this two table  when sem = 1 
like 
output  for  sem =  1
  result

### | B |

1. | cc |
2. | ee |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with an `outer join` and a `where` clause.  In this case, a right outer join, I think:

```
SELECT cd.cGenotype
FROM  dbo.TestResults tr right outer join
      dbo.CombinedData cd
      ON (tr.TestResult = cd.cGenotype)
where tr.testresult is null
GROUP BY cd.cGenotype
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. I look forward to the day when I am as good as you at t-sql.

Answer (score 10):

You could try something like this.

```
SELECT B
FROM Table2 b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 a
    WHERE a.A = b.B)
```

From what I can gather, the reason why yours isn't working is because your getting all the values that ARE in both table1 and table2. What you should be doing is like what I did above. Get all the values that are in both tables and check which values in both tables are NOT within the result set, that is why i have set up a sub-query. I'm a little rusty on my SQL so take what i've said with a gain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.cGenotype
FROM  dbo.CombinedData b 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM dbo.TestResults a 
                  WHERE a.TestResult = b.cGenotype)
```